# Creating AD Groups of computers in each AD OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to use PowerShell to create Active Directory security groups that contain computers from its source OU. The computers in the "ACCT" OU would be in a security group "ACCT", computers in "IT" OU would be in a security group "IT", and so on.

I have the individual commands but am having trouble putting them together.

```
# List Of OUs
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=XX,OU=XXX,DC=XXXX,DC=COM" | FT Name, DistinguishedName

# Computers within the OU
Get-ADcomputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=$_name,OU=XXX,DC=XXXX,DC=COM"

# Add Computer to the group
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity (name of OU) -Members (computers in ou)
```

I have tried a number of solutions found on the web and here but have been unsuccessful. Can someone help me out and point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your on the right track, I just played around with this a bit on my end and I'll give you the advice not to try and do this in a single pipeline, Get-Adcomputer does not have a parameter set that makes that easy to do with a searchbase as your passed object.  You'll want to store your OU's into an array(Drop the formatting command when doing this) and then loop through it doing 3 things: Create a group with New-ADgroup(if needed) and save the name into a variable, Get a collection of all computers in the OU and save to a variable, then use Add-AdGroupmember to add the computers to the group

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually run this code, but it should work.

```
# List Of OUs
$OUList = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=XX,OU=XXX,DC=XXXX,DC=COM" | FT Name, DistinguishedName

foreach ($OU in $OUList)
{
    $searchString = '"OU=' + $OU.Name.ToString() + ',OU=XXX,DC=XXXX,DC=COM"'
    $memberComputers = get-adcomputer -searchbase $searchString
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $OU.Name.ToString() -Members $memberComputers

}
```

Comment: Im getting closer. Thank you. Now im seeing the error "get-adcomputer : The supplied distinguishedName must belong to one of the following partition(s): 'DC=xxx,DC=com" . I have piped out the $searchbase variable and it seems fine. Any suggestions? Thanks again. Peter